# Enable keyboard on the right side of emulator SDK Tools 21.1

Tags: android, keyboard, emulation

I have the latest Android Development Tools and SDK Tools  (Revision 21.1) and cannot seem to enable the keyboard normally seen on the right side of the emulator.  I also cannot seem to find the relevant settings inside the Edit Device dialog.  Any help here?

Answer (score 0):

You can also issue a command from the keyboard. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

And If you enter manual resolution in AVD it will not show keyboard just select any default resolution keyboard will start showing up

Comment: How do I select a default resolution?  The set resolution for Nexus S is 480x800.  Not to mention I can't edit hardware properties from inside the device manager.

Comment: there is dialog box keyboard and skin make them enable

Comment: I have that set, but the keyboard option is for a hardware keyboard.